# VB.NET, SQL Server and list of dates

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters

I have a query that takes as a parameter a list of dates.  In VB.NET the dates are in a string `ArrayList` and I am using the `String.Join()` method to get them in a comma delimited list.  The problem is when I do that double quotes are put at the start and end of the string and SQL complains about that (I think; see below).  How can I get a list of date from a string `ArrayList` without the quote.

My arraylist contains these values:

```
'2020-08-30'
'2020-08-27'
'2020-09-28'
'2020-09-09'
'2020-08-31'
'2020-08-29'
```

when I join them using `String.Join(",", sDates)` I get the following:

```
"'2020-08-30','2020-08-27','2020-09-28','2020-09-09','2020-08-31','2020-08-29'"
```

and when I use that in a parameter query it gets rejected.
`comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dates", String.Join(",", sDates))`

sql contains the following"

```
...where pj.ProjectName =@projectname And tcd.Date in (@dates)
```

Exact error I get is

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    HResult=0x80131904
    Message=Incorrect syntax near ','.
    Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

Any advice?

Comment: The correct way to do this is by using a table valued parameter.

Comment: Might also be one of those instances where addwithvalue is working against you.  Not knowing what the data types tcd.Date is but you may find AddWithValue is assuming you're working with strings and your comparing against a date column

Comment: ^^^ [Can we stop using AddWithValue Already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: When you say "I have a query" do you mean a stored procedure? If so can we see the stored procedure as part of the question?

Comment: What is the datatype of tcd.Date?

Comment: Use sp_executesql [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15]

Comment: Thanks for you help but as it turns out that wasn't where the issue was.  I had a bad value in the sql query I was constructing within VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

Is not caused by the way you've done your IN. It is caused by something else, such as a misplaced comma in a select block:

```
SELECT , a FROM x
       ^
```

The way you've done your IN won't work either, because it's conceptually the same as writing this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateColumn IN ('''2000-01-01'',''2000-02-01''')
```

There is no such date with a string value of `'2000-01-01','2000-02-01'`.

If you want to use IN in the style you're attempting here, you have to add a parameter per date value and set it up accordingly:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateCol IN("
Dim p = 0
For Each d as DateTime in MyDateList
  sqlCommand.CommandText &= "@p" & i & "," 'concat param placeholder on
  sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" & i, d)
  i += 1
Next d

sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlCommand.CommandText.TrimEnd(","c) & ")" 'get rid of trailing comma and close the IN brackets
```

This will generate an sql like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateCol IN (@p0,@p1,@p2)
```

with 3 parameters, and a populated parameters collection. You've already been pointed to Joel's blog about AddWithValue, so I won't repeat it.. But i did want to say that the way you've presented your question implies you have a list of strings, not datetimes. You should definitely make sure your list has DateTimes in, and your db column should be a date based type, not a string based type